# How to delete a subnet with SoftLayer api and Java client?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Couldn't find any example or documentation.
Looking at python cli tool:
http://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/SoftLayer/managers/network.html#NetworkManager.cancel_subnet

It seems like I have to delete billing item matching the subnet id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Nelson Raul Cabero Mendoza's answer, this code worked for me to delete a subnet.

```
public void deleteSubnet() {
    ApiClient appClient = new RestApiClient().withCredentials("user", "api-key");
    List <com.softlayer.api.service.network.Subnet> subnets = Account.service(appClient).getSubnets();
    for (com.softlayer.api.service.network.Subnet subnet : subnets){
        if (subnet.getId() == 1310845L){
            Item billingItem = subnet.asService(appClient).getBillingItem();
            billingItem.asService(appClient).cancelService();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's rigth practically all the Softlayer Services have a billing Item , if you want to cancel the service you need to cancel the billing Item.

The subnet services provides a method to retrieve the associated billig item 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet/getBillingItem

once you have the billing item you can proceed to cancel it using>
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelService

ig you need an example in Java let me know, but practically if you call those methods above using Java you shouldn't have any problem to cancel the item.

Regards

Comment: Code example would be nice if you already have one. I am about to try to write it myself, will post it here if it works.